# How to use *ngFor to show rows of data in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to use * ngFor to create new "rows" as new categories are being added.

The problem is that when running the program, I do not receive any error but also do not get the intended. I've tried to add a few things, but everything under in * ngFor not "running" ... can anyone help me?

```
  GetCategory() {

    var self = this;
    this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
      self.uploadService.getCategory().then(function (resultado) {

        if (resultado) {

          // self.category = resultado; 
          var categories = JSON.parse(resultado);
         // console.log(categories);

        } else {

        }
      }).catch();
    });
  }
```

```
 <div class="bodyPermCardDam">
    <div *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
        <ng-template>
            <div class="categoryChoosedName catParm{{category.ID}}" (click)="SelectCategoryPerm(category.ID,1)">
                <svg class="folder" id="folder{{category.ID}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="19.2" viewBox="0 0 24 19.2">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .folder:hover .stSpecial,
                        .folder:active .stSpecial {
                            fill: #4981C2 !important;
                        }

                        .stSpecial {
                            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <g transform="translate(-32 -92)">
                        <g transform="translate(28 84)">
                            <path class="stSpecial" d="M13.6,8H6.4a2.389,2.389,0,0,0-2.388,2.4L4,24.8a2.4,2.4,0,0,0,2.4,2.4H25.6A2.4,2.4,0,0,0,28,24.8v-12a2.4,2.4,0,0,0-2.4-2.4H16Z" fill="#caced5" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg> {{category.Name}}
            </div>        
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: categories = [ ];
this.categories = JSON.parse(resultado);

Comment: already tested it doesn't load the categories

Comment: is JSON.parse(resultado)  an array?

Comment: yes, 
I needed to convert this to an array because otherwise it would give * nfor an error

Comment: @John : Feel free to upvote as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ng-template` and your code should show results inside `*ngFor`. That's how `<ng-template>` works.

You need `ng-container` to render `ng-template`. [Check this out](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

```
 <div class="bodyPermCardDam">
    <div *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
            <div class="categoryChoosedName catParm{{category.ID}}" (click)="SelectCategoryPerm(category.ID,1)">
                <svg class="folder" id="folder{{category.ID}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="19.2" viewBox="0 0 24 19.2">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .folder:hover .stSpecial,
                        .folder:active .stSpecial {
                            fill: #4981C2 !important;
                        }

                        .stSpecial {
                            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <g transform="translate(-32 -92)">
                        <g transform="translate(28 84)">
                            <path class="stSpecial" d="M13.6,8H6.4a2.389,2.389,0,0,0-2.388,2.4L4,24.8a2.4,2.4,0,0,0,2.4,2.4H25.6A2.4,2.4,0,0,0,28,24.8v-12a2.4,2.4,0,0,0-2.4-2.4H16Z" fill="#caced5" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg> {{category.Name}}
            </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare a public list of categories in the component :

```
public categories : any[];

GetCategory() {

   var self = this;
   this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
   self.uploadService.getCategory().then(function (resultado) {
       if (resultado) {
         this.categories = JSON.parse(resultado);
       } else {

       }
      }).catch();
   });
}
```

and in the view wait for the data by adding an *ngIf :

```
<div class="bodyPermCardDam" *ngIf="categories">
    <div *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
         ...    
    </div>
</div>
```